# When you upgrade a crafted item, does it become soulbound?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

With WoD you can actually craft some powerful epics and upgrade them to a higher item level with a craftable item. I plan on making a [rifle](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/item/109168) for hunters to sell on AH for example.

If I use [True Iron Trigger](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/item/119822) on it, will that make it soulbound or can I still sell it afterwards?

Comment: I should point out the Linkgrease Locksprocket is for i640 goggles, not i630 guns, so you wouldn't be able to use it on the rifle.

Comment: @Psychemaster Small oversight. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It does not make the Item soulbound**

Rerolling stats or upgrading the item level of a crafted item does not make it soulbound. You can use as many rerolls as you like (well and 2 upgrades) on an item and still sell it afterwards.

Comment: Does it also keep any enchantments, like Gift or Breath enchantments, when upgraded?

Comment: Yes, enchantments DO remain on an item after it is upgraded.